# lisawray's groupie library is giving me a headache

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, groupie

I'm learning Android development, while following a tutorial made by Lets Build this App ( on Youtube ).
He used this library and I tried too, but I'm failing. I created a RecyclerView and tried to make a GroupAdapter using Groupie like this:

```
newmessage_view.adapter = groupAdapter
```

This is what he does in the video, but when I do it, it gives me an error:

> ```
> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> (RecyclerView.Adapter<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>?..RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?)
> Found:
> GroupAdapter<com.xwray.groupie.ViewHolder>
> ```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: looks like you did something wrong in your code. Sorry for obvious note, but nothing more to say here.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but how can I work my way around this?

Comment: looks like your `GroupAdapter` does not extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Answer (score 4):

In the new version of Groupie, you need to do as follows

```
    val adaptor = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
```

and make sure to add

```
    import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.GroupieViewHolder
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were using the newest version 2.3.0, change to 2.1.0. It works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin you need to create adapter this way

```
val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i was also following same tutorial and was facing same issue but i resolved by replacing Recycler.Viewholder to GroupieViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to:

```
val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
```

AND remember to override **createViewHolder** if using the groupie legacy approach

```
class MyItem(...) : Item<MyItem.MyViewHolder>() {
    ...
    override fun createViewHolder(itemView: View) = MyViewHolder(itemView)
    ...
    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : GroupieViewHolder(view) {
        // Bind Views
    }
}
```